# Why isnt my code working?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript, and when I press the left or right button, the contact information should change. Nothing happens when I press the left or right button though, why?

```
var currentIndex = 0;

var contact1 = {};
contact1.name = "Fred";
contact1.phone = "555-555-5555";
contact1.birthday = "1/1/1970";
contact1.imageURL = 
"https://images.code.org/53a5bdfb7f4ec83174756c8e094558fd-image- 
1449518131328.png";

var contact2 = {};
contact2.name = "Steve";
contact2.phone = "609-889-4738";
contact2.birthday = "3/15/1992";
contact2.imageURL = 
"data:image/jpeg;base64,";

var contact3 = {};
contact3.name = "Sarah";
contact3.phone = "304-812-4509";
contact3.birthday = "6/23/2001"
contact3.imageUrl = "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jIOlaKwINSQ/Wni55";
var contacts = [];
appendItem(contacts, contact1);
appendItem(contacts, contact2);
appendItem(contacts, contact3);

console.log(contacts);

showCurrentContact(setText("contactInfo","Name: "+ 
contacts[currentIndex].name + "Phone: "+contacts[currentIndex].phone 
+"Birthday: " +contacts[currentIndex].birthday));

onEvent("viewContactsScreen", "keydown", function(event) {
  if(event.key == "Left"){
    currentIndex--;
    currentIndex = wrap(currentIndex, 0, contacts.length-1);
    showCurrentContact();
  } else if (event.key == "Right"){
    currentIndex++;
    currentIndex = wrap(currentIndex, 0, contacts.length-1);
    showCurrentContact();
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hard for anyone to help without a [mcve]. Also report any errors that are thrown. Would be good time to take a few minutes to review [ask]

Comment: Put a proper title for the specific question. Use a jsfiddle if you can to put the entire code, not only the js code.

Comment: @pmirnd Please don't ask for JS Fiddle's because links to 3rd party sites can die over time. Code can/should be inserted, right here in the question as a "code snippet".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not using `event.key` correctly.

Try using `event.key == "ArrowLeft"`
and `event.key == "ArrowRight"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key